# How can I take a picture of an area of the screen using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I made a camera that uses AVFoundation to take a picture of the full screen area. I would like to take a picture only of the middle 250x250 frame of my camera. Similar to the image below:

[image]

I am interested in the full view showing on the phone screen but only the marked square appearing in the picture.

Comment: If you take the full frame then crop it, won't it accomplish the same thing?

Comment: That should work but it's quite a long process because I hope to use the camera for Optical Character Recognition.

Comment: isn't there a way it can be done without cropping?